# How to make this code faster in python (algorithm question)

Tags: python, java, c++, algorithm

Today I was browsing for some questions that I saw this:
Algorithm - Air Battle

C ++ time limit: 1 second
Java time limit: 2 seconds
Python time limit: 10 seconds
Memory limit: 256 MB

There are a number of fighters in a line, and all of them have different heights from the ground. Each fighter can only target its front fighters, provided that their height are less than the height of the fighter that is Under investigation.

The number of fighters that a fighter can target is called a strategic number. For example, if Fighter A can target 3 fighters, we say that the strategic number of Fighter A is 3.

Get the total strategic numbers of all the fighters.

Entraces:
In the first line of input, n appears, which indicates the number of fighters. Then in the next line, the height of the n fighters comes in sequence from h_i.

```
    0001≤n≤100 000
    0001≤h≤100 000
```

Output:

In the output, print the sum of the strategic numbers of all the fighters.

Sample input 1:

5

5 4 3 7 6

Sample output 1
4

I wroted this code for it (in python) but the time limit will be passed in huge numbers:

```
n = int(input())
players = list(map(int, input().split()))
c = 0
for index, player in enumerate(players, 1):
    c += len([num for num in players[index:] if num < player])
print(c)
```

Comment: why tagging unrelated languages?

Comment: Because the answer can be in all of the languages tagged and maybe you know the answer but in another language =)

Comment: Maybe going backward and "accumulate" strategic numbers for heights, using properties like sn(h) ≥ sh(h') if h>h'???

Comment: @Amir.Gh:  So you are accepting answers to a Python language issue in another language.  Cool.  How about LISP, SNOBOL, Algol, or FORTRAN?  I think the answer should be given in LISP.

Comment: Idea 1: If a fighter A can attack a fighter B then it can also attack all the fighters B can attack. This will work for small number of fighters. Idea 2: Insert all fighters into a sorted (by height) binary tree. On each insertion add the number of fighters left of the new fighter. Idea 3: instead of inserting fighters at the same height twice make each node have a height and a count.

Comment: @Amir.Gh your question is specifically about a solution in Python. "knowing a solution in Java or C++" is not relevant to that

Answer (score 0):

The approach is largely similar to [counting inversions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/) in an array.

During the merge step, maintain two pointers (one for each half). Let the two elements from each being compared be `i` (from the left half) and `j` (right half). If `i<j`, `i` will also be smaller than all elements to the right of `j`. You can accordingly increment `i`'s count, and move its pointer. This "hint" should be enough for you to implement a solution.